# Black screen on boot after NVIDIA driver installation

Tags: boot, nvidia

I was downloading Lutrix on Ubuntu because I want to play some games. I was following a YouTube video how to do it, and it suggested to open Additional Drives, click the first driver and apply the change (I think it is NVIDIA driver-53x last number not sure). I also downloaded `freetype` after that, and after several restarts, this message showed up:

```
dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 535287/122028032 files, 33646183/488102912 blocks
[   2.854407] nouveau 0000:01:00-0:-0nknown chipset (194000a1)
[   4.503508] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
```

[image: image of black screen with message]

Comment: Does Ubuntu not boot afterwards? If it boots, then you can safely ignore this message.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1483806/edit) and tell us what are the instructions you followed, step by step. If we don't know what you did, we cannot help much just by guessing.

Comment: Hello, no, the Ubuntu did not boot after this and stayed at this interface. I was following a YouTube video how to do it, and it asked me to click in additional drives and clicked  the first driver and apply change(I think it is NVIDIA driver-53x last number not sure), I also downloaded freetype after that, and after several restart, it became like this @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: Video link: https://youtube.com/watch?v=EhwcxAteKcc&si=81Ma9ua0-2Wi06CU

Comment: @karel I saw that post as well and I tried every method it mentioned but it didn’t help

Comment: Hi Tingb! What kind of graphics card are you using? Can you access the grub menu and select recovery mode?

Comment: @Béné Hi，I am using Geforce Rtx 4070ti, I can access grub and recovery mode